# RadComboBox Items Sorting with RadComboBoxSort.None

Tags: sorting, telerik, radcombobox

What happens to RadComboBox's Items after you call:

```
myCombo.Sort = RadComboBoxSort.None;
myCombo.Items.Sort();
```

???

Even when sort option is set to `None`, Items are sorted, but it is not sorted neither by `Text` nor `Value`. An items are ordered by random pattern which make no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SortItems() method instead of Items.Sort().

Documentation says that these approaches are equal:

```
RadComboBox1.SortItems();
RadComboBox1.Items.Sort();
```

That is not exactly true. If Sort property is set to None, SortItems leaves items unsorted, but Items.Sort will do something unexpected.